# Mongodb hangs, process running db.killOps not working

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb 3.0.4 which stop responding. I checked currentOp which show 70 ops in progress, I tried killing:

```
db.killOp(1701)
{ "info" : "attempting to kill op" }
```

But it has no impact.

To make it up again I need to kill mongo by `kill -9 [processid]` and restart it again.

Answer (score -1):

> db.currentOp({$all : true})
>   the above query will return information on all in-progress operations, including operations on idle connections and system operations.

Choose the Correct OPid and pass it in db.killOp(opid)

It will work perfectly if you're using 'MASTER'